# SWT Browser: a dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse RCP app uses SWT browser to display some predefined html page. At one Windows machine I always have error when Browser component is opening:  *a dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed*. I'm absolutely sure that something is wrong with the environment on this particular PC, because error is reproducible only there. Any ideas about possible reasons?

Answer (score 0):

There is an SWT FAQ about Browser widget: https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#whatisbrowser
You can try creating a Mozilla browser in Windows: https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla